# Docker container running but browser refuse to connect

Tags: windows, docker

I played around `stop, delete, start` etc for docker containers. Maybe somehow I was wrong. But I assume the container is still running because I saw it from the command below.

[image: demo]

However when I typed the `100.55.10.78:5004` on the browser, I got

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 100.55.10.78 refused to connect.

There is only one container and one image. Using `curl localhost:5004`. I get

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Why?

Comment: From where did you take the ip?

Comment: @ItayB, from WINDOWS. The ip is a Linux server, docker engine is installed there. I have docker toolbox installed on my Windows desktop as well. It used to be working. It fails after I played a few actions such as rm start, maybe mess up. But why?

Comment: Did you try docker ps -a to see if another container is up with the same configuration? Did you verify from inside your container that the web service is up (curl localhost:5004)?

Comment: @ItayB, there is only one container and one image so far. See my updated.

Comment: Can you add the command which start your container plz?

Comment: @ItayB, I don't recall it. Perhaps it was ` docker -H tcp://10.50.10.28:2375 start ce37`. The container ID is `ce370b31abb`.

Comment: Can you kill the container, close the toolbox terminal, the virtual box and start it all over again? (BTW did you change something related to network? Ethernet to/from WiFi? Virtual box network settings?)

Comment: @ItayB, It is just not working even I killed it and start it.

Comment: Double click on the default VM (in virtual box). You should see the boot2docker terminal and the IP should appear there as well. Is it the same one you are trying to reach?

Comment: Is the linux server opened the port 5004 on the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best answer. But I had to republish it and override the previous one with the original code. Same port `5004`.

I use the command

```
 docker -H tcp://100.55.10.78:2375 ps
```

And find that the original container is gone, the new container with a different ID is created. There is still one container and one image running. There is no any stopped container.